# Pipelined функция прекращает выполнение?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть запрос, который возвращает найденные `route` по парам `id`, разделенных точкой с запятой.
Например, он вернет `route` для входных данных *"12;13;"*. Также я ожидал, что для нескольких таких пар будет возвращен результат с найденными `route`. Но это не так. Если на его входе есть несколько `id` от заведомо не существующих записей, то не возвращается ничего.

Например , заведомо правильная пара *"12;13;"*. Запрос *"12;13;14;15"* возвращает мне нужный `route`. Запрос же *"14;15;12;13"* не возвратит ни одного, если для пары *"14;15;"* не существует значения.

Сам запрос выглядит примерно так:

```
function get_list(p_ids clob) 
  return obj_list pipelined  --(obj_list это table of rec_obj)
is
  v_rec_obj rec_obj; --(rec_obj это record)
  v_id_list id_list;
begin
  select column_value
    bulk collect into v_id_list
    from table(split2(p_ids, ';')); --split2 возвращает разделенные `id` 
  for i in 1..v_id_list.count - 1 loop
    select r.origin_id, r.dest_id, r.data_object
      into v_rec_obj
      from route r
     where r.origin_id = v_id_list(i) 
       and r.dest_id = v_id_list(i+1);

    pipe row(v_rec_obj);
  end loop;
end;
```

Ну и достается это все потом по типу:

```
select * from table(get_list(p_ids => p_ids));
```

Comment: предполагаю, что ваша функция должна завершаться с ошибкой `no_data_found` в случае, когда запрос внутри цикла не возвращает результата для не существующих `origin_id`. Попробуйте делать `pipe` только в случае, когда строки найдены

Comment: Еще у вас в цикле все время идут переключения контекста. Если скорость важна, эффективнее будет выбрать все значения в коллекцию и из нее уже делать pipe

Comment: Спасибо, @Viktorov
Это помогло мне в решении проблемы. Действительно проблема была в `NO_DATA_FOUND`. Если вы оформите это в качестве ответа, я бы мог отметить его, как верный

Comment: Мне лениво. Вы можете самостоятельно  оформить это в качестве ответа. Возможно кому то поможет)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поведение некоторых исключений в PL/SQL и SQL контекстах могут существенно отличаться. Например, `ORA-01403: no data found` в PL/SQL контексте должно быть обработано:

```
exception when no_data_found then <действие>
```

А в SQL контексте это же исключение возникает при любом запросе, будет отловлено в SQL движке и означает всего лишь, что открытый курсор не имеет больше данных для `fetch`. Другими словами, необработанное исключение `no_data_found` из PL/SQL функции вызванной в SQL контексте будет понято: **нет больше данных** и запрос завершится **нормально**.

---

На упрощённом и воспроизводимом примере можно подробнее увидеть, что не так в функции из вопроса (подготовку схемы см. ниже). Такой запрос для тестовых данных:

```sql
select * from route;

 ORIGIN_ID    DEST_ID DATA                                                            
---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
        11         12 route 1                                                         
        12         13 route 2                                                         
        13         14 route 3                                                         

3 rows selected. 

select *
from table (getRoutes (routeIdList (11,12,15,12,13)))
;

 ORIGIN_ID    DEST_ID DATA                                                            
---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
        11         12 route 1                                                         

1 row selected. 

ORA-01403: no data found
```

завершится без ошибок, но ожидаемая строка к существуюшей паре значений `12,13` не будет получена из-за необработанного исключения к паре значений `12,15`.
В pipelined функциях не стоит забывать обработать [`NO_DATA_NEEDED`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/tuning.htm#GUID-4B0E1C6B-8C73-4905-9E97-37C2667D2184__CHDEEGJD).

И в зaключение, как упомянуто в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-58D850B2-A416-47EA-8803-8936E2D6748A), любая функция должна быть завершена выражением `RETURN`:

> As in every function, every execution path in a pipelined table function **must lead to a RETURN statement**, which returns control to the invoker. However, in a pipelined table function, a RETURN statement need not return a value to the invoker.

И хотя в последних версиях выглядит, что это не является необходимым и работает также и без `RETURN`, но пока трудно предсказать, где будет исправлена ошибка в следующих релизах, в документации или в поведении функции.

---

Подготовка схемы для примера:

```sql
create table route (origin_id number, dest_id number, data varchar2 (64))
/
create or replace type routeRow force is object (origin_id number, dest_id number, data varchar2 (64));
/
create or replace type routeList is table of routeRow;
/
create or replace type routeIdList is table of number; 
/
create or replace function getRoutes (ids routeIdList) return routeList pipelined is
    route routeRow;
begin
    for i in 1..ids.count-1 loop
        select routeRow (r.origin_id, r.dest_id, r.data) into route
        from route r
        where r.origin_id = ids (i) and r.dest_id = ids (i+1) 
        ;
        pipe row (route);
    end loop;
    return;
exception when others then
    dbms_output.put_line (sqlerrm);
    raise;
end;
/
insert into route
    select rownum+10, rownum+11, 'route '||rownum
    from xmlTable ('1 to 3')
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Как и предположил @Viktorov, проблема заключалась в ошибке no_data_found. При её возникновении останавливалось выполнение функции.

Решение конкретно моей проблемы состояло в обработке этого исключения. К примеру, приведенная в вопросе функция стала бы выглядеть так:

```
function get_list(p_ids clob) 
  return obj_list pipelined 
is
  v_rec_obj rec_obj;
  v_id_list id_list;
begin
  select column_value
    bulk collect into v_id_list
    from table(split2(p_ids, ';'));
  for i in 1..v_id_list.count - 1 loop
    begin
    select r.origin_id, r.dest_id, r.data_object
      into v_rec_obj
      from route r
     where r.origin_id = v_id_list(i) 
       and r.dest_id = v_id_list(i+1);

    pipe row(v_rec_obj);

    exception when no_data_found then
      null;

    end;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: в функцию приходят значения парами? [origin_id;dest_id;origin_id;dest_id;...] если так, то внутри цикла нужно увеличивать i, а еще лучше сразу делить на две коллекции что наверное проще сделать через регулярные выражения

Comment: @РавшанАбдулаев не обязательно они должны быть парными. Пара может образоваться и на следующей итерации цикла. Например, для [1-2-3] будет две пары [1-2] и [2-3]. Просто в контексте самого вопроса это было не так важно

Comment: я выше добавил ответ, где так же обрабатывается ситуация когда в таблице route более одного совпадения, сейчас поправлю чтобы обрабатывались ситуации  [1-2] и [2-3]

Comment: @JohnGrave Да, не забудте так же `no_data_needed` обработать, а то добавите код в функцию и будете опять удивлятся, почему она вдруг завершается.

Answer (score 0):

проверьте [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/20a73/1)

```
    create table route (
      origin_id NUMBER,
        dest_id NUMBER,
    data_object VARCHAR2(100)
    )
    //

    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE D_OBJ 
    IS

      type obj_rec is record(
        origin_id NUMBER,
          dest_id NUMBER,
      data_object VARCHAR2(100)
      );

      type obj_list is table of obj_rec;

      function get_list(p_ids in clob) return obj_list pipelined;

    end D_OBJ;
    //

    -- create package body
    -- create package body
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY D_OBJ IS

      function get_list(p_ids in clob)
        return obj_list pipelined
      is
        TYPE t_num_col_typ is table of number;
        l_origin_id_col t_num_col_typ;
        l_dest_id_col t_num_col_typ;
        l_result obj_rec;
        l_result_tbl obj_list;
      begin
        WITH T AS ( SELECT p_ids AS STR FROM DUAL )
      SELECT to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR(T.STR, '[0-9]+', 1, LEVEL, 'm')),
             to_number(REGEXP_SUBSTR(T.STR, '[0-9]+', 1, LEVEL+1, 'm'))
        bulk collect into l_origin_id_col, l_dest_id_col
        FROM T
     CONNECT BY LEVEL < REGEXP_COUNT(T.STR, '[0-9]+', 1, 'm');
        for i in 1..l_origin_id_col.count loop
          select r.origin_id, r.dest_id, r.data_object
            BULK COLLECT INTO l_result_tbl
            from route r
           where r.origin_id = l_origin_id_col(i)
             and r.dest_id = l_dest_id_col(i);

            for j IN 1..l_result_tbl.count loop
              pipe row(l_result_tbl(j));
            end loop;
        end loop;
      end get_list;
    end D_OBJ;
    //
-- execute the public procedure of the package
begin
  insert into route( origin_id, dest_id, data_object) VALUES (21, 201, 'obj 1');
  insert into route( origin_id, dest_id, data_object) VALUES (31, 301, 'obj 2');
  insert into route( origin_id, dest_id, data_object) VALUES (41, 401, 'obj 2');
end;
//
select * from route
//
-- dbms_output doesn't work, so we log into a table 
-- (just like in real life) and select all records from it here
select * from table(D_OBJ.get_list(p_ids => '21;201;
                                             31;302;
                                             41;401'))
//
```